# Why can't I debug into UnityEngine.UI code?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I add the **UnityEngine.UI.dll** and UnityEditor.UI.dll to my assets folder with their mdb files . also i add the both project to my current project. i am sure all the unity engine ugui code build success, because i debug log in the event system, and it print message. when i want to step into the  event system class, i always failed . I find unity will load the code from a build path ,rather than i original code. Why does it do this ? if i want to debug unity engine ugui code, what should i do ?

Comment: it's really unclear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

To debug code, you need two things:

1. Symbols, the list of all functions, classes, variables used throughout the module. When using C++ symbols are stored in special .pdb files on Windows (and you obviously are using Windows since you are talking about dlls). Symbols in C# (.NET in general) are stored in the .dll itself. Having symbols will let you see the name of functions on the call stack and possibly some variables but nothing more.
2. Source code of the module.

U3D's source code is proprietary - you need to spend a good amount of money to receive it. And if I am guess to - UnityEngine.UI.dll is a C++ module with stripped (removed) symbols removed.

Thus you have neither, so you can't debug U3D's code *at all*.

Why would you need to that anyway? If you want to see how the internals of a big game engine work, there are plenty of other options (for example UE4 and Lumberyard). If you are struggling with a problem and you'd like to be able to solve it through debugging...well though luck. Your best bet would be to ask in unity community.